# $EXITVAL not working with capture in perl

Tags: perl

I need to run a Perl script from a Perl script, save the output in a log file and display an error message if I get an error. I don't want the script to end, just print the message that a call had failed. I am using capture to do this but I am unable to print the error message conditionally.

I referred to [this link](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple#runx(),-systemx()-and-capturex()), particularly this text:

> $EXITVAL The exit value of any command executed by IPC::System::Simple
> can always be retrieved from the $IPC::System::Simple::EXITVAL
> variable:
>
> This is particularly useful when inspecting results from capture,
> which returns the captured text from the command.
>
> *use IPC::System::Simple qw(capture $EXITVAL EXIT_ANY);   my
> @enemies_defeated = capture(EXIT_ANY, "defeat_evil", "/dev/mordor");
>
> print "Program exited with value $EXITVAL\n";*
>
> $EXITVAL will be set to
> -1 if the command did not exit normally (eg, being terminated by a signal) or did not start. In this situation, an exception will also be
> thrown.

This is my code:

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw(capture EXIT_ANY $EXITVAL);
my $output = capture(EXIT_ANY, $tool_path);
if($EXITVAL == -1){
        print "CHECK_FLOW: Error! check. Check the log file mem_check.log\n";
}
else{
        print "CHECK_FLOW: Completed check.\n";
}
my $filename = 'check.log';
open(my $fh, '>', $filename);
print $fh "$output\n";
close $fh;
```

I inserted an error in the $tool_path purposely and used the debugger which shows the $EXITVAL to be 0 in both cases.

Is there anything I am missing? Is there any other way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: What kind of error did you put into your script? A syntax error? Or did you make it `die`? Or `exit 1`?

Comment: I gave wrong arguments- should return exit 1.

Comment: The docs say it will always set `$EXITVAL` to `-1` in case of an abnormal exit, which is anything other than `0`. But it doesn't seem to do that. Strange. I can't run it right now though, so cannot be of much further help. Does it throw the exception if you remote the `EXIT_ANY`?

Comment: Re "*I gave wrong arguments- should return exit 1.*", Well, it didn't if `$EXITVAL` is zero as you claim

Comment: Note that your code will never enter the `if` because `capture` throws an exception when it sets `$EXITVAL` to `-1` (according to the very text you quoted, and confirmed through experimentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) to do this. Your use-case is actually the first in the synopsis of the docs.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Capture::Tiny;

my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture {
  system( './foo.pl', @args );
};

if ($exit) {
    warn 'something went wrong when executing foo.pl';
}
```

Comment: When passing multiple arguments to system(), the first argument must only be the executable. So it would be `'perl foo.pl'`, or `'perl', 'foo.pl', @args`.

Comment: @Grinnz it's late over here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to your unsupported claims, it does work as documented.

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );

use IPC::System::Simple qw( capture EXIT_ANY $EXITVAL );

{
   my $output = capture(EXIT_ANY, 'perl', '-e', 'print "abc\n"; exit(123);');
   print("<$_>\n") for split /\n/, $output;
   print("$EXITVAL\n");
}

print("--\n");

{
   my $output = capture(EXIT_ANY, 'non-existent');
   print("<$_>\n") for split /\n/, $output;
   print("$EXITVAL\n");
}
```

Output:

```
<abc>
123
--
"non-existent" failed to start: "No such file or directory" at a.pl line 15.
```